# blueimp jquery file upload background color on Firefox

Tags: jquery, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I noticed on Firefox only (even on [online demo](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/)) that when selecting a file for upload, the table row background acts weird: some parts have the light gray background, and other parts are white; I have to resize the window or "move things" for having a full light gray background

I also noticed that problem goes away if I remove the "fade" class from the `<tr>` in the template (but then I lose also the fade-in effect)

No problem on Chrome

Is there a fix for this, please? Thank you

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have look at the css code that its using from bootstrap its seems the `fade.in` is the problem

original css bootstrap code

```
.fade.in {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

adding some timing to fade in (in this case 0 seconds) seems to fix the issue

```
<style>
.fade.in { 

-webkit-transition: opacity 0s linear;
   -moz-transition: opacity 0s linear;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0s linear;
     -o-transition: opacity 0s linear;
        transition: opacity 0s linear;

}
</style>
```